# Delphi ReportBuilder Error: Unable to locate ppReport.pas

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I am using reportbuilder 15.

I included unit `ppReport`, declared an object `rptBuilder1 = TppReport` in my pas file from where I have to call the print function. In my code while printing the report, I am using following line to call reportbuilder function

```
rptBuilder1.Print;
```

while pressing `Ctrl + Click` on `Print` method, RAD studio is not taking me to the ppReport.pas file which is there in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\11.0\RBuilder\Source`

**Note:** I have already included above path in delphi environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but it worked. I removed the path of RBuilder from Environment Options and then added again. `Ctrr+Click` worked.